# Is it possible to inline string without const enum?

Tags: typescript, constants, compile-time-constant

I want to expoort string contsnt but in such way that it would be inlined in all places it is used it and variable von't be created. I know it's possible with `const enum`:

```
const enum SomeEnum {
    SOME_VALUE = "SOME_VALUE"
}

alert(SomeEnum.SOME_VALUE);
```

compiles into

```
"use strict";
alert("SOME_VALUE" /* SOME_VALUE */);
```

But I'm interested in making dotless access to the value, i. e. I want to write

```
alert(SOME_VALUE);
```

and I want it to be compiles into the same thing.

**How can I declare `SOME_VALUE` to archive that?**

Comment: Not possible without const enum. And even const enums use them sparingly, they are not compatible with babel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2020-09, you cannot,

Here's a discussion about such a feature — inline constants — over at the Typescript GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3964

**Update:** Now that issue [got closed](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3964#issuecomment-696328159):

> given the feedback so far and the risk of the feature, it's safe to say this isn't happening

So, likely Never, then.